# Download File Missing Inserted Data

Tags: asp.net, response, oledb, outputstream

A feature of a legacy website that I support is the ability to download a data extract. After the application is deployed, the extract appears to complete successfully but the file downloaded only doesn't contain any data in any of the tabs. The logic is that a blank Excel template of 10 sheets (containing only the headings) is populated from data read from a database and inserted into the tabs.

```
// Copy the template to the relevant folder
const string templateFilename = "DataExtractTemplate.xlsx";
var templateFullPath = Server.MapPath($"~/Administration/Templates/{templateFilename}");
var templateFileInfo = new FileInfo(templateFullPath);
var temporaryFile = Server.MapPath($"~/Administration/ExtractOutput/{templateFilename}");
templateFileInfo.CopyTo(temporaryFile, true);
templateFileInfo = new FileInfo(temporaryFile) { IsReadOnly = false };
// Download the file to the user's downloads folder
Response.Clear();
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=DataExtract.xlsx");
Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", templateFileInfo.Length.ToString());
Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
Response.TransmitFile(templateFileInfo.FullName);
Response.Flush();
Response.Close();
Response.End();
templateFileInfo.Delete();
```

I have confirmed that the data is being loaded into the datatable, and as far as it appears, each row is inserted into each worksheet of the copied template, but the file that I end up with is identical to the file I started with, i.e. an empty template. I have confirmed that the file is being copied correctly on the server and that the parameters are being populated from the data using the code below.

```
// Get the relevant OleDbType based on the column type
internal static OleDbType GetOleDbType(string systemType)
{    
    OleDbType returnType;
    switch (systemType)
    { 
         case "Double":
         case "Int32":
            returnType = OleDbType.Numeric;
            break;
        default:
            returnType = OleDbType.VarChar;
            break;
    }

    return returnType;
}

// Create delimited list of column names
var columnParams = dataTable.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>()
    .Aggregate(string.Empty,
               (current,
                       column) => current + $"@{column.ColumnName},");
columnParams.TrimEnd(',');
// Create parameters for each row and insert into the worksheet
int insertedRows = 0;
foreach (DataRow dataRow in dataTable.Rows)
{
    oleCmd.Parameters.Clear();
    oleCmd.CommandText = $"INSERT INTO [{tabName}$] VALUES ({parameterValues})";
    var columnCount = 0;
    var parameters = new List<OleDbParameter>();
    foreach (DataColumn column in dataTable.Columns)
    {                                      
        var dataColumnName = column.ColumnName;
        var dataTypeName = column.DataType.Name;                    
        var dataRowItemValue = dataRow[columnCount];                    
        var isItemNull = string.IsNullOrEmpty(dataRowItemValue.ToString());
        var parameter = new OleDbParameter { ParameterName = $"${dataColumnName}", SourceColumn = dataColumnName, OleDbType = GetOleDbType(dataTypeName) };
        if (!isItemNull)
        {            
            switch (dataTypeName)
            {
                case "Double":
                case "Int32":
                case "DateTime":
                    parameter.Value = Convert.DBNull;
                    break;
                default:
                    parameter.Value = string.Empty;
                    break;
            }
        }
        else
        {            
            var cellValue = dataRow.ToString();
            switch (dataTypeName)
            {
                case "Double":
                    parameter.Value = double.Parse(cellValue);
                    break;
                case "Int32":
                    parameter.Value = int.Parse(cellValue);
                    break;
                default:
                    parameter.Value = cellValue;
                    break;
            }
        }
    
        parameters.Add(parameter);
    }

    oleCmd.Parameters.AddRange(parameters.ToArray());
    insertCount += oleCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    rowCount++;
}
```

Each ExecuteNonQuery succeeds, i.e. returns 1, yet no data is written to the template. Oddly, it seems to work for a similar extract that uses nearly all the same code, but the output is corrupted. This extract has 21 columns of data for 4-500 rows and this is the error I get when opening it:
[image: Corruption error]

Comment: Hum, my best guess is the data not being pulled on the server. The code looks ok, as as you note, it works during local testing. Did any of the data pull + downloads EVER work on the server? I mean, obviously the connection path used on produciton will be VAST different.

Comment: I certainly did work for many years, and then just stopped. I'm pretty sure it stopped working prior to the move from on-premise to Azure, but I've got the relevant team checking out the logs for the server to see if there's anything obvious. 
The temp file location has also been there for years, but agree, better it's moved to a designated folder. I'm making some improvements, so I'll look at that.

Comment: I also know the data is getting to the server as the datatable that is populated contains the expected number of rows.
This is an example log written on the actual server:  
Running as Martin Swanston on 01 February 2024 14:11  
Stored Procedure Name: usp_GetAllResultsData
Tab Results expecting 4,165 rows
Tab Results received 4,165 rows  
Temporary file:C:\Windows\TEMP\tmp51C6.XLSX  
Buffer length:36934 bytes  
Response.Status BEFORE Write:OK  
Response.Status AFTER Write:OK

Answer (score 0):

Best guess is data not being pulled on the server. The code looks ok, and as noted works during testing local. Did any of the data pull + downloads EVER work on the server?

I mean, obviously the connection path used on production will be VAST different.  You might want to add some test page to the application with a few buttons such as "database connect test". Or a button to pull rows, and shove the row count into a text box on the same page.

Remember, the production IIS server version running HAS TO match the bit size of the installed version of Access data engine. So, enable x32 bit application pool if you using Access x32.  I

I would also NEVER use ANY cpu, but force the project to run as x32 bits, or force the project to run as x64 bits. As noted, if you force project to run as x64 bits, then the x64 bit version of the Access data engine has to be installed on the server.

So, that path to the temp file? Gee, did some previous code place that file in the temp folder? I'm not all that convinced that placing a Excel file in the windows temp folder is a good idea. I would create a folder in the project, and use sever.mappath() to get that file location, and that Excel file thus should be placed in a better folder location, since on a hosted server, you may well have some rights and restrictions for the windows folder.

Answer (score 0):

I initially thought this was an issue at the coding side - when copying the blank template into it's new location, the path of the blank template was being passed back, not the copied file.

```
const string templateFilename = "DataExtractTemplate.xlsx";
var templateFullPath = Server.MapPath($"Templates/{templateFilename}");
var templateFileInfo = new FileInfo(templateFullPath);
var temporaryFile = Server.MapPath($"ExtractOutput/{templateFilename}");
templateFileInfo.CopyTo(temporaryFile, true);
templateFileInfo = new FileInfo(templateFileInfo) { IsReadOnly = false };
return templateFileInfo.FullName;
```

The penultimate line should have been:

```
templateFileInfo = new FileInfo(temporaryFile) { IsReadOnly = false };
```

I've also swapped the windows temp folder for a folder within the project as suggested, so no permissions are needed for C:\Windows\Temp, but still seeing the same issue.
Here is the latest log:
Running as Martin Swanston on 02 February 2024 12:57
Connection string:Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data
Source=C:\Webs\web-n-rsgpsd\Administration\ExtractOutput\DataExtractTemplate.xlsx;Extended Properties='Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES'
Stored procedure name: usp_GetAllResultsData
Tab Results expecting 4,165 rows
Tab Results received 4,165 rows
Temporary file:C:\Webs\web-n-rsgpsd\Administration\ExtractOutput\DataExtractTemplate.xlsx
Buffer length:36,934 bytes
It's clear that the file downloaded is only 37kb, but why is the data for the query downloading 4k rows but that data isn't being passed into the relevant worksheet?

Comment: what does var buffer = client.DownloadData(exportFile); do??? Consider using              Response.TransmitFile(strServerFile) for this. Given you verifted the templ file has all the data and rows (I assume you have), then the issue is transmission of the file, and thus using transmit file is a better choice.

Comment: How do I verifying that the file on the server has the data and rows? I'm confirming that the ExecuteNonQuery call returns a record for each row added, but the length of the buffer is the file without any data. I did get back some data from the server logs, and I'm seeing 'Exception type: NullReferenceException' and 'Exception message: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.' so need to figure out where that is happening.

Comment: I've figured out where it is falling over, but cannot for the life of me figure out why! It builds the CREATE TABLE script for one of the tabs that contains 91 columns, but as soon as it attempts to assign the CommandText to the OleDbCommand object, it just falls over. The length of the command text is 2,323 characters.

Comment: Well, go to the server and find the saved file, and look at the length? (how hard is that?). I mean, even if this is hosted, you can still ftp to the files for that site, or in most cases near all systems will have some type of file browse system (all of my hosting plans have some dashboard panel that happens to include a file browse utility). I also have a global error trapping, and it sends me a email for any error that occures on the site -- so boatloads of approaches here exist. As I stated, this sounds like the ACE provider is not available on that server, or it x32 bit version.

Comment: Thus, as my post below notes, force your project to run as x32, and NEVER use ANY CPU for the project build, but force the project to run as x32 bits.

Answer (score 0):

After adding in oleCmd.Prepare() prior to the ExecuteNonQuery line, inside a try/catch, I got the following error regarding VarChars:
OleDbCommand.Prepare method requires all variable length parameters to have an explicitly set non-zero Size.
This was easily fixed, but once resolved, the next error for numeric values came up:
OleDbCommand.Prepare method requires parameters of type '131' have an explicitly set Precision and Scale.
I just need to figure out how to proceed, but at least I'm making progress!